# Tomcat secure folder in webapps

Tags: tomcat, contextpath

I have a web application and Tomcat, like server for it.
I put my web app in the folder: `$(TOMCAT_HOME)/webapps/myapp` and my images to the `$(TOMCAT_HOME)/webapps/images`
And I wrote next in the tomcat's **server.xml**

```
<Context path="/images" docBase="c:/servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/images"/>
```

It works OK. 
But, I wanna to secure the folder. I mean, I want to banned access to the folder if user is not logged in my application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to put a  in your deployment descriptor. Something along the lines of this:

```
<security constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Images</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>

    <web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        <role-name>Member</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>

<security-role><role-name>Admin</role-name></security-role>
<security-role><role-name>Member</role-name></security-role>
<security-role><role-name>Guest</role-name></security-role>
```

You will then need to define the user roles in a tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename=”Admin”/>
    <role rolename=”Member”/>
    <role rolename=”Guest”/>
    <user username=”Conor” password=”admin” roles=”Admin, Member, Guest” />
    <user username=”SomebodyElse” password=”coder” roles=”Member, Guest” />
    <user username=”Andrew” password=”newbie” roles=”Guest” />
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Edited to include security-role element.

Comment: Thank you 4 answer. But, could you please explain. If I add the **<security-constraint>** to my **app's** **web.xml** How is it help me? The web.ml has access only in the application folder.  For example: my app is on URL: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/start.jsp` and my images are on URL: `http://localhost:8080/images/img/ef8e1b70541a.jpg`   How the **web.xml** from myapp can control access to the folder?

Comment: Your web.xml can only limit access to resources within that project, so it can't define rules for the images folder where it is(to the best of my knowledge). Would it be feasible for you to move the images to "http://localhost:8080/myapp/images/kitten.jpg" ?

Comment: Here is what oracle say on the matter:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bncck

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can't move images into **webapp** :( If it would so, I will not ask the question on the forum :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, for anyone coming to this post, I faced a similar problem and found a workaround,

[Tomcat 7 - Secure a folder under webapps folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18142353/186896)