# Tomcat 7 - Secure a folder under webapps folder

Tags: security, authentication, tomcat

My web application is 'myweb', within this web app my code refers '123.pdf' under 'files' folder like http://`localhost`:8080/files/123.pdf

```
   webapps  
   |  
   |--myweb  
   |  
   |--files  
       |  
       |--123.pdf
```

I want the resource (123.pdf) available only for logged in users, when I try to access directly by pasting (http://`localhost`:8080/files/123.pdf) in the browser address bar, without logging into the portal, I could access the file.

Basically I want to secure the 'files' folder under 'webapps', so that only authenticated users in portal could access resources under 'files' folder. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's what the security constraints in web.xml are for.

Comment: @EJP I tried by converting 'files' folder to a web app by adding 'WEB-INF\web.xml', added '<security-constraint>' in web.xml, MemoryRealm in '\conf\server.xml', roles in '\conf\tomcat-users.xml'.If I access directly '123.pdf', tomcat is asking for authentication, at the same time, If I access 'http://localhost:8080/myweb/customerhome' - where I have reference to '123.pdf', tomcat is showing the login popup. How can I login to 'files' web app from 'myweb' web app programmatically, so that users just login to 'myweb' and access excels, pdfs from 'files' folder without getting popups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem. This is what I came up with,

1) Convert 'files' folder to a web application and make files (say pdf) secured by using tomcat's 
FORM based authentication

2) After getting authenticated to 'myweb' - here authentication is not tomcat container based, its based on 
spring & hibernate -

asynchronously invoke a servlet (PopulateServlet.java) in 'files' web app from '/myweb/customerhomepage.jsp' and set tomcat role username & pwd in 'files' web app session

whenever there is a request to protected pdf under 'files' web app, login.jsp will be invoked - in this jsp populate hidden j_username & j_password fields 
          from session object which was already populated by  PopulateServlet. Using jquery ajax, the html form will be submitted to tomcat 
          for resource authentication.

**'files' web app changes:**

*Create new role and user name and password*
    /conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
```

*Create WEB-INF/web.xml*

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Populate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>PopulateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Populate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Populate</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LogOutServlet</servlet-class> <!-- in this servlet, call session.invalidate() -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/jsp/security/protected/*</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>

     <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
     <http-method>GET</http-method>
     <http-method>POST</http-method>
     <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/jsp/security/protected/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/jsp/security/protected/error.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
<security-role>
  <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
</security-role>
```

*Create login.jsp and error.jsp under /files/jsp/security/protected/*

login.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#secure").submit();
});
</script>
...
<form method="POST" action='<%= response.encodeURL("j_security_check") %>' name="secure" id="secure">
<input type="hidden" name="j_username" value='<%=session.getAttribute("j_username")%>' />
<input type="hidden" name="j_password" value='<%=session.getAttribute("j_password")%>' />
</form>
...
```

*PopulateServlet.java*

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("j_username","tomcat");
session.setAttribute("j_password","tomcat");
```

*'myweb' web app changes:
    customerhomepage.jsp*

```
$.get('/files/Populate?ts='+new Date().getMilliseconds());
```

Comment: At the time of this comment, I could see more than 800 hits to this post, I request fellow SOers to upvote my answer if its useful or if anything not clear, let me know, I can update my answer. Upvotes 
to my answer will keep me motivated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add another configuration in your spring web config:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("reports/**")
            .addResourceLocations(reportsRootPath);
}
```

`reportsRootPath` is defined in properties file which could be any file System location.

Files are accessible like; reports/myReport.pdf

Here is the [documentation](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) which guided me