# Tomcat basic authentication for specific URL only

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, server, xampp

I am working in JSP and servlet. I want to deploy two web applications in the same server but different URLs.

I need to set a basic authentication for two web application by different user and password

I have configured the following in tomcat.

### In Web.xml file

```
<web-app>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>timesheet</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/timesheet</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>timesheetuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>user password required. Producted by Udhayakumar</realm-name>
</login-config>


<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>testuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>user password required. Producted by Udhayakumar</realm-name>
</login-config>
</web-app>
```

### In tomcat-user.xml file

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="timesheet"/>
<role rolename="test"/>
<user username="timesheetuser" password="test123" roles="timesheet"/>
<user username="testuser" password="test123" roles="test"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

### Tomcat Web Application Manager

[image: Tomcat Web Application Manager]

if I open this URL in my browser not asking for username and password. it is opening directly

- *localhost:8080/timesheet*
- *localhost:8080/test*

I want to use a different user and password to the timesheet and test applications. The above method is not working for me.
Are there any mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

in Web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>testuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>

    </security-constraint>
```

Comment: I want to use different username and password for 1. test and 2. timesheet, not a same user password for both

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142353/tomcat-7-secure-a-folder-under-webapps-folder